# Attaching Click Event To Button's Context MenuItem Within ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a download bar like chrome.

[image: Valid XHTML]

The issue I'm currently having is trying to bind the click event to the button's context menu within the listboxitem. When the context menuitem is clicked, it says the action is not found.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Button BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
        <StackPanel Name="Panel" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="1 0"
                Height="30">

            <ContentControl Margin="0 0 10 0" Height="20">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Icons.File}"></Setter>                            
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>

            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding FileName}"  
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    TextAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="1 0 0 0"/>

            <Button x:Name="ExpandButton" Background="Transparent" Click="ExpandButton_OnClick" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="false">
                <Button.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu x:Name="popup">
                        <MenuItem  Header="Open" cal:Message.Attach="[Click] = [Open($this)]"></MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Icons.ArrowUp}" Width="10" Height="10" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Button>
            <Rectangle Width="2" Fill="Gray" Margin="0 0 0 0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I could bind it behind code(xaml.cs) side of the application but I also lose track of what item is the context suppose to point to. To do that, i replaced caliburn's click event with a regular Click event. The SelectedItem and SelectedItems is null or empty, respectively.

```
private void MenuItem_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var originalSource = e.OriginalSource;
    var selectedItem = FileListBox.SelectedItem;
    var SelectedItems = FileListBox.SelectedItems;
}
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused what you are trying to do. The first photo is a `ListBoxItem` with a button on the far right, correct? And you would like the context menu to open when you click that button on the far right of the `ListBoxItem`?

Comment: @kalamazoowho That's exactly what I'm looking to accomplish. So it doesn't look like you are confused.

Comment: I've done a similar problem with code-behind, but I didn't change the context menu popup from right-click to left-click. You said you lose track of the item the context is pointing to. Do you know what items you can pick from? Like will it always be a `Button` type that the context menu will be pointing to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested but something along these lines should open the context menu on right or left click:

```
<Button x:Name="ExpandButton" Background="Transparent" Click="ContextMenu_Click" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="false">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu x:Name="popup" MenuItem.Click="menuItem_Click">
                        <MenuItem  Header="Open" cal:Message.Attach="[Click] = [Open($this)]"></MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Icons.ArrowUp}" Width="10" Height="10" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Button>
```

As for the code-behind, the following worked for me in my last tug with a similar issue:

```
DependencyObject mainDep = new DependencyObject();

private void ContextMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

    while ((dep != null) && !(dep is ListBoxItem))
    {
        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
    }
    mainDep = dep;
}
private void menuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject dep = mainDep;

    if (dep is ListBoxItem)
    {
        ...
           DO your stuff here
        ...
    }
}
```

Let me know how these work for you

Comment: Hi @Hank, thank you for your answer. It wasn't quite right but it pointed me in the right direction.I kept looking up the VisualTree till I got the ListBoxItem as the parent.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped! So instead of searching for `Button`, like my answer has, you searched for `ListBoxItem`? Just want to make sure the answer is updated for others that may find this post looking for answers